# replacing rowwise() operations in grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

Anonymised example subset of a much larger dataset (now edited to show an option with multiple competing types):

```
structure(list(`Sample File` = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
    Marker = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", 
    "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "q", "q", "q", "q"), Allele = c(19, 20, 
    22, 23, 18, 18.2, 19, 19.2, 20, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 10, 10.2, 
    11, 12), Size = c(249.15, 253.13, 260.64, 264.68, 366, 367.81, 
    369.97, 372.02, 373.95, 91.65, 95.86, 100, 104.24, 108.38, 
    177.51, 179.4, 181.42, 185.49), Height = c(173L, 1976L, 145L, 
    1078L, 137L, 62L, 1381L, 45L, 1005L, 38L, 482L, 5766L, 4893L, 
    19L, 287L, 36L, 5001L, 50L), Type = c("minusone", "allele", 
    "minusone", "allele", "ambiguous", "minushalf", "allele", 
    "minushalf", "allele", "minustwo", "ambiguous", "allele", 
    "allele", "plusone", "minusone", "minushalf", "allele", "plusone"
    ), LUS = c(11.75, 11.286, 13.375, 13.5, 18, 9, 19, 10, 20, 
    12, 11, 14, 15, 16, 9.5, NA, 11, 11.5)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), groups = structure(list(
    `Sample File` = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), Marker = c("X", "Y", 
    "Z", "q"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:9, 10:14, 15:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I want to look up values based on the classification `$Type`.

- "minustwo" means I want to look up the "Allele", "Height" and "LUS"
  values for the row with "Allele" equal to t*he current row plus two*,
  with the same `Sample File` and `Marker`.
- "minusone" means the same but for "Allele" equal to the current row plus one.
- "minushalf" means the same but for "Allele" equal to the current row plus 0.2 but the dot values here are 25% each, so 12.1, 12.3, 12.3, 13, 13.1 etc - I have a helper function `plusTwoBP()` for this.
- "plusone" means the same for "Allele" equal to the current row -1
- "allele" or "ambiguous" don't need to do anything.

Ideal output:

```
# A tibble: 18 × 10
# Rowwise:  Sample File, Marker
   `Sample File` Marker Allele  Size Height Type        LUS ParentHeight ParentAllele ParentLUS
   <chr>         <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <chr>     <dbl>        <int>        <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 A             X        19   249.     173 minusone   11.8         1976           20      11.3
 2 A             X        20   253.    1976 allele     11.3           NA           NA      NA  
 3 A             X        22   261.     145 minusone   13.4         1078           23      13.5
 4 A             X        23   265.    1078 allele     13.5           NA           NA      NA  
 5 A             Y        18   366      137 ambiguous  18             NA           NA      NA  
 6 A             Y        18.2 368.      62 minushalf   9           1381           19      19  
 7 A             Y        19   370.    1381 allele     19             NA           NA      NA  
 8 A             Y        19.2 372.      45 minushalf  10           1005           20      20  
 9 A             Y        20   374.    1005 allele     20             NA           NA      NA  
10 B             Z        12    91.6     38 minustwo   12           5766           14      14  
11 B             Z        13    95.9    482 ambiguous  11             NA           NA      NA  
12 B             Z        14   100     5766 allele     14             NA           NA      NA  
13 B             Z        15   104.    4893 allele     15             NA           NA      NA  
14 B             Z        16   108.      19 plusone    16           4893           15      15  
15 C             q        10   178.     287 minusone    9.5         5001           11      11  
16 C             q        10.2 179.      36 minushalf  NA           5001           11      11  
17 C             q        11   181.    5001 allele     11             NA           NA      NA  
18 C             q        12   185.      50 plusone    11.5         5001           11      11
```

I have a rather belaboured way of doing it:

```
# eg for minustwo
sampleData %>%
  filter(Type == "minustwo") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ParentHeight = sampleData$Height[sampleData$`Sample File` == `Sample File` & sampleData$Marker == Marker & sampleData$Allele == (Allele + 2)],
         ParentAllele = sampleData$Allele[sampleData$`Sample File` == `Sample File` & sampleData$Marker == Marker & sampleData$Allele == (Allele + 2)],
         ParentLUS = sampleData$LUS[sampleData$`Sample File` == `Sample File` & sampleData$Marker == Marker & sampleData$Allele == (Allele + 2)]) %>%
  right_join(sampleData)
```

I then have to redo that for each of my Types

My real dataset is thousands of rows so this ends up being a little slow but manageable, but more to the point I want to learn a better way to do it, in particular the `sampleData$'Sample File' == 'Sample File' & sampleData$Marker == Marker` seems like it should be doable with grouping so I must be missing a trick there.

I have tried using group_map() but I've clearly not understood it correctly:

```
sampleData$ParentHeight <- sampleData %>% 
  group_by(`Sample File`, `Marker`) %>%
  group_map(.f = \(.x, .y) {
    pmap_dbl(.l = .x, .f = \(Allele, Height, Type, ...){
      if(Type == "allele" | Type == "ambiguous") { return(0)
      } else if (Type == "plusone") {
        return(.x$Height[.x$Allele == round(Allele - 1, 1)])
      } else if (Type == "minushalf") {
        return(.x$Height[.x$Allele == round(plustwoBP(Allele), 1)])
      } else if (Type == "minusone") {
        return(.x$Height[.x$Allele == round(Allele + 1, 1)])
      } else if (Type == "minustwo") {
        return(.x$Height[.x$Allele == round(Allele + 2, 1)])
      } else { stop("unexpected peak type") }
    })}) %>% unlist()
```

Initially seems to work, but on investigation it's not respecting both layers of grouping, so brings matches from the wrong `Marker`.  Additionally, here I'm assigning the output to a new column in the data frame, but if I try to instead wrap a `mutate()` around this so that I can create all three new columns in one go then the `group_map()` no longer works at all.

I also considered using `complete()` to hugely extend the data frame will all possible values of `Allele` (including x.0, x.1, x.2, x.3 variants) then use `lag()` to select the corresponding rows, then drop the spare rows.  This seems like it'd make the data frame enormous in the interim.

**To summarise**

This works, but it feels ugly and like I'm missing a more elegant and obvious solution.  How would you approach this?

Comment: sample data updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two versions of Allele: one identical to the original Allele, and one that is equal to an adjustment based on `minusone`, `minustwo`, etc

Then do a self left join, based on that adjusted version of Allele (and Sample File and Marker)

```
sampleData = sampleData %>% group_by(`Sample File`,Marker) %>% mutate(id = Allele) %>% ungroup()
left_join(
  sampleData %>% 
    mutate(id = case_when(
      Type=="minusone"~id+1, 
      Type=="minustwo"~id+2,
      Type=="plusone"~id-1,
      Type=="minushalf"~ceiling(id))),
  sampleData %>% select(-c(Size,Type)),
  by=c("Sample File", "Marker", "id"),
  suffix = c("", ".parent")
) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 10
   `Sample File` Marker Allele  Size Height Type        LUS Allele.parent Height.parent LUS.parent
   <chr>         <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl>         <int>      <dbl>
 1 A             X        19   249.     173 minusone   11.8            20          1976       11.3
 2 A             X        20   253.    1976 allele     11.3            NA            NA       NA  
 3 A             X        22   261.     145 minusone   13.4            23          1078       13.5
 4 A             X        23   265.    1078 allele     13.5            NA            NA       NA  
 5 A             Y        18   366      137 ambiguous  18              NA            NA       NA  
 6 A             Y        18.2 368.      62 minushalf   9              19          1381       19  
 7 A             Y        19   370.    1381 allele     19              NA            NA       NA  
 8 A             Y        19.2 372.      45 minushalf  10              20          1005       20  
 9 A             Y        20   374.    1005 allele     20              NA            NA       NA  
10 B             Z        12    91.6     38 minustwo   12              14          5766       14  
11 B             Z        13    95.9    482 ambiguous  11              NA            NA       NA  
12 B             Z        14   100     5766 allele     14              NA            NA       NA  
13 B             Z        15   104.    4893 allele     15              NA            NA       NA  
14 B             Z        16   108.      19 plusone    16              15          4893       15  
15 C             q        10   178.     287 minusone    9.5            11          5001       11  
16 C             q        10.2 179.      36 minushalf  NA              11          5001       11  
17 C             q        11   181.    5001 allele     11              NA            NA       NA  
18 C             q        12   185.      50 plusone    11.5            11          5001       11
```

Comment: Apologies for not including it in the sample data, I was trying to keep it minimal, but there will be some groups where a single `allele` type will have minustwo, minusone, minushalf AND plusone types associated.  This means incrementing the id by 1 won't always work.  I have amended the example in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the further work - this is good for the toy dataset and I think will work reasonably for my real dataset as well with a bit of tweaking.  I will mark it as solved.